# Propositions ,Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

John made the following statements:
1.I love Lucy
2.If i love Lucy then i love Vivian.

Given that john  either told the truth  or lied in both cases.Determine whether John really loves Lucy.What that suppose to mean .Determine if Jonh really loves Lucy? How s that possible to determine?Suppose it means to determine if statement 1 is true always. Let p="John loves Lucy" and q="John loves Vivian"  .If p is false  then statement 2 is True since the definition "p-->q=If p then q" is true if p is false  Or  both true .Which cant lead me to say that p is always true .What does the author want me to prove .And i dont make any sense  to propositions in math like "Determine whether John really loves Lucy." Can you prove mathematically if john loves really lucy by what he said.I find the approach of the author very bad. I read a book for my Discrete mathematics Course  and the author is C.L.Liou

Comment: Yeah I don't understand the question. Further, if the question is asking to determine if "John loves Lucy" is always true, I don't think you have enough information. Is this everything given in the problem?

Comment: It's not possible to determine this, unless there's a hidden assumption that one can love only at most one other person.

Comment: can i prove that statement 1 is always true even if someone can love at most one person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is that statement "If I love Lucy then I love Vivian" is an implication.   Under *classical logic*†, if this implication is a lie, then its negation is the truth: "I love Lucy and I not love Vivian".

John makes the statements of the form: $L$ and $L\to V$.   We are to assume either both are true or both are false.

- If both are true then we accept both and conclude that John loves Lucy and Vivian too via: $$\{L, L\to V\} ~\vdash~ L\wedge V$$
- If both are false, then we negate both and conclude the result is *inconsistent*. $$\{\neg L, L\wedge \neg V\} ~\vdash~\bot$$

  We argue that as John is presumed to be *consistently* either *truthful* or *lying*, rather than *babbling*.   Thus John is truthful, and loves Lucy and Vivian too.

---

(† Constructive, or Intuitional, Logic disagrees that the negation of an implication is an assertion of its falsification.)